# Solving matrix equations over $p$-adic rings

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, p-adic-number-theory

Let $F/\mathbb{Q}_p$ be a finite extension, and let $\mathcal{O}_F$ be its ring of integers. Now for $ 0< i,j \le r$ let $B_{i,j} \in \mathit{Mat}_{n \times n}(\mathcal{O}_F)$ be some matrices and let $M$ be the block matrix, whose $i,j$ block is given by $B_{i,j}$ and let $D$ be the block diagonal matrix with blocks $B_{i,i}$ along the diagonal (so both $M,D$ have the same size). I would like to know when it is possible to find a matrix $X$ (in $\mathit{Mat}_{rn \times rn}(\mathcal{O}_F)$ ) such that $M=XD$.

In general I wouldn't like to have to assume that $D$ is invertible.

thank you.

Comment: In general I think this question is very hard even with the "usual" fields, and I'm not sure if it has a definite general answer.

Comment: The existence of such $X$ is equivalent to the condition that the span of the rows of $B_{ii}$ contains the span of the rows of $B_{ji}$ for all $1\le i,j\le r$.Thus, one necessary condition (that is possibly easier to check) is $\operatorname{rank}(B_{ji}) \le \operatorname{rank}(B_{ii})$ for all $1\le i,j\le r$.

Comment: Also, the existence of such $X$ is equivalent to $\ker(B_{ii}) \subseteq \ker(B_{ji})$ for all $1\le i,j\le r$. I don't know, which is more convenient for you.

Comment: What do you mean by rank in this context? since I'm not working over a field.

Comment: The rank is defined as the maximal number of linearly independent columns (or rows). Use that a family of vectors is linearly independent over $O_p$ if and only if they are linearly independent over $F = \operatorname{Frac}(O_p)$ to see that the rank also makes sense over $O_p$.

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean. The thing tha worries me is that I can't see why the solution $X$ has to be a matrix over $O_p$ and not $Frac(O_p)$.